# Objective-C iOS - Best way for a piece of code to run itself N fixed number of times and recursively retry forever or until conditions are met?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Objective-C iOS - Best way for a piece of code to run itself N fixed number of times and recursively retry forever or until conditions are met?

Here is the problem. I have to send an image for printing on a bluetooth printer. The problem lies in the fact that I need it exactly 3(N) times, and in between those prints problems can arise, printer becomes unreachable, replace paper or something else. I need to let the user maybe try to fix the problem (turn the printer on and off, put some paper in) between each print try.

The program has to do this forever no matter what. If he can't print, he can't continue. 
The PrinterClass is supplied by the manufacturer and it has @try @catch in there also, catching errors when they appear.

Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
- (void)tryToPrint{
    @try {
        copy++;
        [PrinterClass printImageSource:imageToPrint printerWidth:1200];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        copy--;
    }
    @finally {
        if (copy <= N) {
            [self tryToPrint];
        }
    }
}
```

PS. Copy is set to 0 outside the method.

Comment: try/catch is rarely a good technique in Objective C.  Does the printer API offer other ways of detecting errors? As for your question, I would look at a GCD serial dispatch queue - simply queue the task as many times as is needed.  If a task fails then it can re-queue itself.

Comment: No... not really. At low level the Printer framework tries to write the commands to some port, and it gives at least 60sec to complete. It can produce just one error "Write timeout". If you want to know anything more you have to check the status struct for information, and then display a message based on that. My question isn't really focused on the printer itself but rather on the program retrying, I've never used GrandCentralDispatch so I'm stuck.

Comment: The concurrency programming guide will help - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way, add a completion block to your method definition:

```
-(void)tryToPrint{
[self print:^(bool success) {

    if (success) {
        //ok do what you want
    }else{

        [self tryToPrint];
    }
}];}
-(void) print:(void (^)(bool success))completionBlock{}
```

And then in your main class call:

```
[self tryToPrint];
```